# How can I target a SwiftUI app for Apple TV

Tags: swiftui, tvos

I'm creating an app in SwiftUI. I have it running on Mac and iOS.

How do I get it to run on my Apple TV?

I've never developed for Apple TV before. Can I run the existing app and see what it looks like on the TV. Thanks for any tips you can share.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to add a new target for tvos.  In your project settings click the + button under targets, then select the tvos tab, and choose Single View App.

Finish creating the target, make sure you select SwiftUI for the user interface.

You should have a new tvos folder under your project, go to AppDelegate.swift and change the UIHostingController to point to your main SwiftUI view.

```
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: YourMainView())
```

You may need to go to your swift source files and check that the target membership includes tvos

[image: Target Membership]

Change your run target to tvos, and click run.

[image]

You will probably have to do some work to support the tvos platform in your app, some of the swiftUI user input events are pretty different in tvos.